# Detect focus/blur between two iframes (Accessibility)

Tags: html, iframe, accessibility

Inside of a page, there are 2 iframe buttons (external, not from the same origin as my site) next to each other that grab the focus when a keyboard user focusses to them.

I need to style them (for accessibility reasons) when the user is focussed on them. Since iframes grab the focus, the page has no control over the focus styles inside the iframes so i have made custom borders to go around the iframe when the main window loses focus. [The first iframe has an indicator, yay!]

**BUT** I realized when you are tabbing **BETWEEN** the 2 iframes (from the first to the second), the browser cannot detect that action. It is as if it skips form one iframe to the next without notifying the main window of anything. Therefore, I can never style the next iframe and unstyle the first...

I have tried everything even down to using the sandbox attribute to force same origin, which ends up causing issues with these social media iframes (*i am warned in the console that they will not pass the iframe to me within a sandbox, once again... rightfully so*). Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You need control of the site at the other side of iframe, otherwise Same Origin Policy will apply.

Comment: Yes, that was what i thought... I tried as much as I could to detect between the iframes but it seems to jump directly into the next one.

Comment: Is there something about those 2 buttons you need but can't replicate like unique content?

Comment: @zer00ne They are social media buttons that hold all the functionality to like or follow my account.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot just make links without relying on the embedded bits? Something similar to how [Simple Sharing Buttons](https://simplesharingbuttons.com/) does it (though you will need to change how icon fonts are handled because the accessibility is broken [per issue 8](https://github.com/fourtonfish/SimpleSharingButtons/issues/8), [issue 9](https://github.com/fourtonfish/SimpleSharingButtons/issues/9) and [issue 10](https://github.com/fourtonfish/SimpleSharingButtons/issues/10))